# LWJGL Drop Shadow on 2D Quad Shapes

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, shadow

I am a hobby developer, and I love quality graphics. I am fairly familiar with LWJGL quads and drawing shapes with them.

What I am unfamiliar with is binding those shapes to a texture and then applying shaders to such (if that is the solution, I don't know). My current objective for my project is to add high quality diffused drop shadow to quad style shapes, rectangles, circles, etc.

Here is an example of the effect I am aiming for drawn in photoshop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/udq3X.png

Please explain to me how I can add such a shadow to my shapes.

(THE SHADOW CAN BE INDEPENDENT OF THE EXISTING SHAPE)

Comment: So this is just about 2D shapes?

Comment: Yes, my mistake for not being as descriptive as necessary.

Comment: Here is one way to do it: Make the quads bigger than they need to be.
 (because you can't draw outside the quad). Then when you render it the fragment shader adds the shadow. I've written an [example](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4styRB), but its far from perfect and very resource heavy.